# Why Elasticsearch snapshot stats number_of_files differs from actual indices count?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an indice called `traces_v2` aliased as `traces` with 5M document.

I did `GET /_snapshot/s3_repository/snapshot_traces_250316/_status`and two minutes later the status was:

```
{
   "snapshots": [
      {
         "snapshot": "snapshot_traces_250316",
         "repository": "s3_repository",
         "state": "SUCCESS",
         "shards_stats": {
            "initializing": 0,
            "started": 0,
            "finalizing": 0,
            "done": 8,
            "failed": 0,
            "total": 8
         },
         "stats": {
            "number_of_files": 185,
            "processed_files": 185,
            "total_size_in_bytes": 654459334,
            "processed_size_in_bytes": 654459334,
            "start_time_in_millis": 1458898771760,
            "time_in_millis": 81226
         },
         "indices": {
            "aliases": {
               "shards_stats": {
                  "initializing": 0,
                  "started": 0,
                  "finalizing": 0,
                  "done": 5,
                  "failed": 0,
                  "total": 5
               },
               "stats": {
                  "number_of_files": 5,
                  "processed_files": 5,
                  "total_size_in_bytes": 795,
                  "processed_size_in_bytes": 795,
                  "start_time_in_millis": 1458898819263,
                  "time_in_millis": 1491
               },
               "shards": {
                  "0": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 1,
                        "processed_files": 1,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898820308,
                        "time_in_millis": 110
                     }
                  },
                  "1": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 1,
                        "processed_files": 1,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898820674,
                        "time_in_millis": 80
                     }
                  },
                  "2": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 1,
                        "processed_files": 1,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898819263,
                        "time_in_millis": 101
                     }
                  },
                  "3": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 1,
                        "processed_files": 1,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898819617,
                        "time_in_millis": 108
                     }
                  },
                  "4": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 1,
                        "processed_files": 1,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 159,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898819916,
                        "time_in_millis": 86
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "traces_v2": {
               "shards_stats": {
                  "initializing": 0,
                  "started": 0,
                  "finalizing": 0,
                  "done": 3,
                  "failed": 0,
                  "total": 3
               },
               "stats": {
                  "number_of_files": 180,
                  "processed_files": 180,
                  "total_size_in_bytes": 654458539,
                  "processed_size_in_bytes": 654458539,
                  "start_time_in_millis": 1458898771760,
                  "time_in_millis": 81226
               },
               "shards": {
                  "0": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 58,
                        "processed_files": 58,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 213816982,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 213816982,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898814476,
                        "time_in_millis": 38510
                     }
                  },
                  "1": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 55,
                        "processed_files": 55,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 253988996,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 253988996,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898771760,
                        "time_in_millis": 47244
                     }
                  },
                  "2": {
                     "stage": "DONE",
                     "stats": {
                        "number_of_files": 67,
                        "processed_files": 67,
                        "total_size_in_bytes": 186652561,
                        "processed_size_in_bytes": 186652561,
                        "start_time_in_millis": 1458898771760,
                        "time_in_millis": 42340
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The status was SUCCESS but stats says there was 180 documents (over 5M!) snapshoted. Are those real documents or some kind of folder with millions of docs inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is stored in physical files on disk.
`number_of_files` denotes the total number of files containing the data and not the actual number of documents.

A single file may contain a lot of documents. For instance, in your case, each file may contain an average of 5M/180 docs although it is not guaranteed that every file will contain the same number of docs.

If you look further into details, it contains breakup of shard wise files i.e. total number containing the data corresponding to one shard.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. So it means that only 180 documents was snapshoted in my case? (The details says 58+55+67). Or 180 folders containing a total of 5M?

Comment: No, a single file may contain multiple docs. It is not related to the total number of docs in your index.

Comment: Ha, much more clear. Thx you. And how can I be sure of the total number of documents snapshoted?

Comment: I dont see any such thing in documentation but I feel one way to be certain of is : "total_size_in_bytes": 654459334,
            "processed_size_in_bytes": 654459334. As you can see, total and processed, both sizes are same which means entire data is processed. Also, you can check your current index size(in bytes) and compare with this.

Comment: ho yes, make sense. Thx you for your time.